# Application server architecture: access clustered server application through single address

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, glassfish, application-server

I have been reading countless oracle documents, blogs, etc. but I cannot wrap my mind around this concept.

I have successfully deployed an application to a GlassFish server cluster.  See screenshot:
[image: Application Instances]

I would like to have load balancing and fail over by using a single url address to access my application.

For example currently to get to my application I must use `http://<server-name>:28080/AppName` but I would like to use `http://cluster:28080/AppName` and have an available load balancing service automatically select it.

Currently I have 3 GlassFish 3.1 servers with a basic default setup and GMS. Is GlassFish capable of doing the automatic load balancing and fail over or do I need a web server (like Apache or Oracle IPlanet) in front of my GlassFish cluster to distribute connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Olivier states you need to put a load balancer in front of your cluster. You can use a hardware device or you can use software.

I've used both and each works great. You should read [Configuring Web Servers for HTTP Load Balancing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2426/gchvt.html) for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You need a front-end load balancer (software or hardware).